# How can I calculate the limit of sequence using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Using MATLAB I want to calculate the limit of the sequence below.
$$
a(n)=\frac{n^2+1}{3n^2+1}
$$
$$
\lim_{(n\to\infty)}a(n)=?
$$
At first I thought
\

syms n

a(n)=(n^2+1)/(3*n^2+1);

limit(a(n),'n',inf)

would solve the problem.

However, this couldn't be the answer because the limit is calculated where n is a real number here, while n should be only the natural numbers.
So I think I should use 'while' loop, but I can't figure out how I should use it.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: As far I understand, infinity it isn't natural neither real valued, its a concept and not a number, so for your purposes, while $n$ is not in the complex numbers, you could use equivalently that $n \to \infty$ without having to care if $n$ is a natural number or if its a real number, the succession will converge (if it does), to the same answer.

Comment: If `n` is a natural number, then why not define it specify it as such via: `syms n positive integer`? You'll get exactly the same answer due to the reasons mentioned by @Joako.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the while loop, try to reduce the limit value to a tolerance range using $a(n)>a(n+1)$ for any $n\geq1$. Here is an example:

```
n = 1;
an = (n^2 + 1)/(3*n^2 + 1);
an_prev = an;

while true
    n = n + 1;
    an = (n^2 + 1)/(3*n^2 + 1);
    if abs(an - an_prev) < 1e-256
        break;
    end
    an_prev = an;
end
disp(an);
```